# Compile SQLite to run on Windows Mobile

Tags: c, sqlite, mobile, compilation, windows-mobile-6.5

Here is a link to the source. http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

It is written in C and I need it to run on windows mobile 6.5. Any tips on doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a lack of standard C libraries natively on WinCE, so it looks like you need to find helper libraries which are designed to help porting from Unix to windows mobile, such as WCELIBCEX(http://wcelibcex.sourceforge.net/).

You will also probably have trouble untangling SQLite's TCL build requirement (honestly, I have no idea why they did that, when shell scripts and standard Unix libs would have done just fine).

Happy hacking.

UPDATE: okay, looked a little deeper, and found that you can have the SQLite folks just hand you a C file post-TCL mangling:

```
To simplify matters, SQLite is also available as a pre-packaged amalgamation source
code file: sqlite3.c. The amalgamation is a single file of ANSI-C code that implements
the entire SQLite library.
```

Quoted text from http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html